# Can't validate Post Code on checkout page

Tags: magento2

I tried following [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html) guide but when I test it, it is just triggering regular expression validation I want my to check **postcode** in **API**.

> Here is the code in {module_name}/view/web/js/model/postalCode.js

```
    define(
    [
        'jquery'
    ],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';

        return {

            /**
             * Validate checkout agreements
             *
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            validate: function () {
                var zipValidationResult = false;
                var zip = $('form[postcode]').val();
                alert("WORKING" + zip);
                console.log("WORKING");
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
);
```

> Here us code in {module_name}/view/web/js/view/postalCode.js :

```
     define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Sdu_CheckPostalCode/js/model/postalCode'
    ],
    function (Component, additionalValidators, postalCode) {
        'use strict';
        additionalValidators.registerValidator(postalCode);
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

> And here is code in {module_name}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- Declare your validation. START -->
                                                            <item name="postalCode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Sdu_CheckPostalCode/js/view/postalCode</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <!-- Declare your validation. END -->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that i had heavily customized checkout_index_index.xml page and it just didn't render.